# java calendar on Modal Bootstrap

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

Hi i'm using modal Bootstrap and a calendar inside but when i click the calendar button the calendar appears behind and it must be over the modal. here's the picture.

[image: java calendar on Modal Bootstrap]

this is the java code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
   window.addEvent('domready', function() { 
      myCal1 = new Calendar({ fcap1: 'd/m/Y' }, { blocked: ['12-15,20-22,25 2-5 2008'], direction: 0, tweak: { x: 6, y: 0 } });
      myCal2 = new Calendar({ fcap2: 'd/m/Y' }, { blocked: ['12-15,20-22,25 2-5 2008'], direction: 0, tweak: { x: 6, y: 0 } });

                 });
    //]]>
</script>
```

and this is the Modal Bootstrap

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="modal fade" id="modal-fechacap" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
             <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                     <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Asignar fechas de captura</h4>
                     </div>
                     <div class="modal-body">


                         <input type="hidden"  name="horario" id="horario" value=""/>
                          <p>
                          <label>Materia:</label>
                         <input type="text" name="materia" id="materia" value=""  size='50' maxlength='80' readonly/>
                          </p>
                           <p>
                         <label>Unidad:</label>
                         <input type="text" name="unidad" id="unidad" value="" size='5' maxlength='2' readonly/>

                          </p>
                          <p>
                               <label>fecha inicio:</label>
                              <input type="text" name="fcap1" id="fcap1"/>
                                <label>fecha fin:</label>
                              <input type="text" name="fcap2" id="fcap2"/>

                          </p>
                     </div>

                     <div class="modal-footer">
                          <div style="margin-left:10px">
                           <button type="button" class="fechacap btn btn-success btn-sm" id="fechacap">
                           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Asignar fechas de captura
                           </button> 
                           <a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">
                           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>&nbsp;Cancelar&nbsp;</a>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

All suggestions are welcome and appreciated, thanks.

I updated this code in the calendar.js and worked great!

```
'styles': { left: '-1000px', opacity: 0, position: 'absolute', top: '-1000px', zIndex: 999999 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try writing some CSS to target the calendar and set it's `z-index` to be larger than that of the modal.  Check what the `z-index` is for the modal with a web inspector and make the calendar's `z-index` larger. For example:

```
#calendar {
    z-index: 1000;  
}
```

Comment: i updated this code in the calendar.js

'styles': { left: '-1000px', opacity: 0, position: 'absolute', top: '-1000px', zIndex: 999999 }   

and worked great.. thanks!